# What's the best way to compare the efficiency of splay trees?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, splay-tree

I have implemented several [splay tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) algorithms.

What's the best way to compare them?

Is it a good start to compare execution time when adding random nodes?

I've also implemented an Binary Search Tree that keeps track of how much every node is visited. I wrote an `optimize()` method that creates an Optimal Binary Search Tree.
If we do not plan on modifying a search tree, and we know exactly how often each item will be accessed, we can construct an optimal binary search tree, which is a search tree where the average cost of looking up an item (the expected search cost) is minimized.
How can I involve this in the comparison of splay trees?

Answer (score 2):

I like the empirical approach.

In this approach:

1. Create a bunch of random typical data sets, of various lengths.
2. Run each implementation and find out what is the execution time for each.
3. Use [**Hypothesis testing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) methods to find out if one implementation is better then the other. In here, the [null hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis) (H<sub>0</sub>) is "The two implementations should take the same time to execute, on average.
4. Conclude from step 3 that one implementation is better then the other, with probability `1-p` (where `p` is your [p_value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value)).

PS [Wilcoxon test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) is considered a good one, and is used a lot in literature and research to compare two algorithms.